# PHP looping through array and appending to object

Tags: php, arrays

I have array of objects like so;

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [Job] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [ID] => 123
                    [Name] => Foo
                 )
        )
    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [Job] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [ID] => 456
                    [Name] => BAR
                 )
        )
)
```

I need to loop through the array and append some additional information to the object like 'Status', but I'm having some issues.

```
foreach($arrJobs as $key => $val) {

  $arrJobs[$key]->Job->Status = new StdClass;
  $arrJobs[$key]->Job->Status = $myStatus;

}
```

This appears to work, but I get the following warning;

> Warning: Creating default object from empty value in...

Comment: No warning emitted [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7d0684b4630e5a138fcc37bc9ef6f3ca58e54c10) . Can you update your example to one that actually reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to my understanding to you question you just need to append properties to your existing objects. **Don't create new objects in your loop**

you just need this

```
foreach ($arrJobs as $obj)
{
    $obj->job->status = $myStatus;
}
```

See the full code :

```
<?php
$obj1 = new \stdClass();
$obj1->job = new \stdClass();
$obj1->job->id = 123;
$obj1->job->name = "foo";

$obj2 = new \stdClass();
$obj2->job = new \stdClass();
$obj2->job->id = 456;
$obj2->job->name = "bar";

$array = [$obj1,$obj2];

var_dump($array);
foreach ($array as $obj)
{
    $obj->job->status = "the status";
    //add any properties as you like dynamicly here
}
echo "<br>\nafter<br>\n";
var_dump($array);
exit;
```

Now `$obj1` and `$obj2` has the new property 'status' ,see that demo : (https://eval.in/833410)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, create an object first. You cannot assign properties of `null`. That's why you need an instance of `stdClass`, php's generic empty class.

```
$arrJobs[$key] = new stdClass;
$arrJobs[$key]->foo = 1;

// And/or see below for 'nested' ...
$arrJobs[$key]->bar = new stdClass;
$arrJobs[$key]->bar->foo = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($arrJobs); $i++)
{
    $arrJobs[$i]->Job->Status = new stdClass;
    // other operations
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

**PHP**

```
<?php
    // Sample object creation.
    $array = [];
    $array = [0 => (object) ['Job'=>(object) ['ID'=>123, 'Name' => 'Foo']]];

    foreach($array as $val) {
        $val->Job->Status = (object) ['zero' => 0,'one' => 1]; // Status 0 and 1.
    }

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($array);
?>
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [Job] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [ID] => 123
                    [Name] => Foo
                    [Status] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [zero] => 0
                            [one] => 1
                        )

                )

        )

)
```